# WordPress Ignoring .user.ini

Tags: php, configuration, php.ini

I have a server using Apache and PHP-FPM. The server hosts several WordPress sites with each site  running as a different user and using a different pool.

I'm trying to configure the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` directives on a per-site basis by placing a `.user.ini` file in each site's document root. I know that the `.user.ini` file is being read because `phpinfo()` displays local values from the `.user.ini` file and master values from the main `php.ini` file. I've confirmed this using `ini_get('post_max_size')` and `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` which both return the local values from the `.user.ini` file.

WordPress however, appears to ignore the `.user.ini` file. Plugins such as *WP-ServerInfo* and *WP Server Stats* display local and master values as the same, with the values coming from `php.ini`. I've confirmed this with `ini_get()` from within WordPress and *Media* > *Add New* > *Maximum upload file size: 2 MB*.

`.user.ini` is owned by the user running WordPress with 640 permissions.

| Directive | .user.ini | php.ini | phpinfo() | phpinfo() | WP Plugin | WP Plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Local | Master | Local | Master | Local | Master |
| post_max_size | 64M | 8M | 64M | 8M | **8M** | **8M** |
| upload_max_filesize | 32M | 2M | 32M | 2M | **2M** | **2M** |

I know it's possible to set directives on a per-pool basis using `php_value` or `php_admin_value`, but I'm interested to understand (and a little frustrated) why WordPress appears to be ignoring `.user.ini`.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The comment from @TomJNowell got me thinking. I did a search on what PHP CGI/FPM is passing to WordPress and found [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-activate-optimize-wordfence-firewall-with-php-fpm-fastci-enabled/) describing a similar issue with the Wordfence plugin.

I followed the suggestion of moving `.user.ini` from the document root to the `/wp-admin` directory. WordPress now gets passed the values in `.user.ini`. Conversely, `phpinfo()` doesn't get these values as it's in a script run from the document root, which makes sense.

| Directive | .user.ini | php.ini | phpinfo() | phpinfo() | WP Plugin | WP Plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Local | Master | Local | Master | Local | Master |
| post_max_size | 64M | 8M | **8M** | 8M | **64M** | 8M |
| upload_max_filesize | 32M | 2M | **2M** | 2M | **32M** | 2M |

The post went on to suggest moving `.user.ini` back to the document root then creating a symlink to it in the `/wp-admin` directory. Now both WordPress and `phpinfo()` get the values from `.user.ini`.

| Directive | .user.ini | php.ini | phpinfo() | phpinfo() | WP Plugin | WP Plugin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Local | Master | Local | Master | Local | Master |
| post_max_size | 64M | 8M | **64M** | 8M | **64M** | 8M |
| upload_max_filesize | 32M | 2M | **32M** | 2M | **32M** | 2M |

Not sure this last step is strictly necessary as the directives are for the benefit of WordPress, but it does tie-it-up neatly.

I'm also unsure why my original setup doesn't work, but having `.user.ini` (or a symlink to it) in the `/wp-admin` directory does. Maybe this is more of a hack than the correct way of doing it, but I'm content for now that it works.

Comment: WP itself doesn't load or read `php.ini` or other ini files, that's the responsibility of PHP CGI/FPM. So unless you have a lot of `ini_set` calls somewhere WP is just reporting what it's been given. How exactly are you loading the `.user.ini` file? Also kudos on the markdown table :)

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you. _How exactly are you loading the .user.ini file?_ I'm not explicitly loading it. I _assumed_ it was being read at some point because of the output from `phpinfo()`. Is that the issue? Do I need to explicitly load it? If so, how? _WP is just reporting what it's been given._ Is it possible to track what PHP CGI/FPM is giving WP?

Comment: WordPress has a filter to define the max upload size -- [`upload_size_limit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_size_limit/). You might want to check if anything's hooked to that filter.

Comment: There's nothing to load a `.user.ini` unless you explicitly add a mechanism to add it, otherwise it's just a random file in your folders. It's not that your file is being ignored, it's that nothing knows to load it

Comment: As for what WP is being given, sure, you're already doing that. Keep in mind that all of this is not the responsibility of WP, any more than the oxygen being in the room because you were given oxygen to put there. WP finds itself loaded in a PHP environment that you created, it doesn't construct that environment itself. Both your problem, and the solutions, are all PHP/Apache/Nginx based solutions, not WordPress based.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the clarification Tom. See the update to my original post. Finally got it working :)

Comment: @PatJ Thanks Pat. I had looked at that earlier. The only context I could find it being used was in the  `wp_max_upload_size()` function from `/wp-includes/media.php` which returns the lower of `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: This was exactly the solution for my problem - a symlink to wp-admin!